# An infinite group $G$ and $\forall x\in G, x^n=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be an infinite group and $n\in \mathbb N$. If for any infinite subset $A$ of $G$ there is $a\in A$ such that $$a^n=e,~~~~(e=e_G)$$ then prove that for every element $x\in G$ we have $x^n=e$.

This question was asked me and **honestly** I could not find any way to break it well. I worked on the order of an element $x$ to show that every element is of finite order but it seemed not to complete a solid approach. Thanks for the time!

Comment: Hint: Consider the set of elements obtained from the condition by going through all infinite subsets. How large can the complement of this subset be?

Comment: I misread "any" as "an", and this became a very different question (second sentence).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Can we find a concrete example of such this group? I am just curious about that.

Comment: Sure, take the direct product of an infinite number of copies of any group satisfying $x^n = 1$ for all $x$ (for example any finite group of order $n$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $G$ must be a torsion group: if $x \in G$, then either $\langle x \rangle $ is finite, or $\langle x \rangle$ is infinite. In the latter case $A=\langle x \rangle -\{1\}$ is an infinite set, and hence $x^{kn}=1$ for some integer $k$. In both cases, $x$ has finite order.

Now consider the subset $S$ of $G$ defined by $S=\{x \in G: x^n \neq 1\}$. Assume that $S$ is non-empty. We are going to derive a contradiction from that. Observe that $S$ is a normal subset (i.e. it is closed under conjugation) and, it must be finite. For if it were infinite, then there is an $x \in S$ with $x^n=1$, contrary to the definition of $S$! Now we can apply the [Dietzmann Lemma](http://bit.ly/1m7YlkT): $N:=\langle S \rangle$ is a *finite normal* subgroup of $G$.

Let $g \in C_G(N)$ and assume $g \notin N$, so that $g^n=1$. Let $x \in S$. Then $(gx)^n=g^nx^n=x^n\neq1$. Hence $gx \in S \subseteq N$, and $x \in N$, hence $g \in N$, a contradiction, so after all $g \in N$. This means $C_G(N) \subseteq N$. Finally use the fact that $G/C_G(N) \hookrightarrow \text{Aut}(N)$, which is a finite group. So index$]G:C_G(N)]$ is finite, and we conclude that $G$ must be finite, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly (but only very slightly) different answer:

If $X$ is the set of elements $x$ satisfying $x^n = 1$ then the complement of $X$ is finite by the assumed property.

So if $y$ is some element in the complement, we must have that $N_G(\langle y\rangle)$ has finite index in $G$ (since this index is the number of conjugates of $\langle y\rangle$.

Also, $C_G(\langle y\rangle)$ must be finite, as mentioned in one of the other answers.

Finally, we just need something related to these where we have control of the size. For this purpose, we can use the general fact that for any group $G$ and any $y\in G$, $N_G(\langle y\rangle)/C_G(\langle y\rangle)$ is finite (this is a nice little exercise).

Combining the above yields the desired contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for every words. Shame on me not to solve such this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H$ be the subset of elements such that $x^n = e$. <strike>You may check and see that this is a subgroup.</strike> Also, the difference set $A = G \setminus H$ must be finite (it cannot be infinite by the given condition). Therefore $H$ is an infinite subgroup. But by something like Lagrange's theorem (think about it...), the size of the the complement of a subgroup must be an integer multiple of the size of the subgroup, and particularly, if $H$ is infinite, then $A$ must be infinite or empty. But $A$ is finite, so it is empty.

EDIT: Oops, looks like my unwritten proof that $H$ is a subgroup only works if $G$ is Abelian, so maybe this answer is incorrect. (I'll leave it here, anyway - maybe someone can fix it.)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed Tobias made light on the question. So I am feeling the solution and like you I am thinking to show that it is empty. Thanks :)

Comment: Do u think there is a Lemma or a Theorem explaining that property? I don't know such that fact. Good fact if there exists.

Comment: Why is that set a subgroup?

Comment: Oops - I don't know whether it's a subgroup if the group is not Abelian.

Comment: In fact... Let $G$ be the group generated by $a, b$ with only the relations $a^2 = b^2 = e$. Then $a, b \in H$ but $ab$ is not in $H$ because it has infinite order, so in the non-Abelian case, $H$ might not be a subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $G$ has no elements of infinite order. Suppose there exists $y \in G$ with $|y| \nmid n$. Replacing $y$ with a power of $y$, we may assume $\text{gcd}(|y|, n) = 1$. If $y^G = \{gyg^{-1} \mid g \in G\}$ is infinite, we are done (since $|y| = |gyg^{-1}|$ for any $g \in G$).

On the other hand, if $|y^G| = |G : C_G(y)| < \infty$, then $|C_G(y)| = \infty$, so there exists an infinite sequence of distinct elements $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ in $C_G(y)$ with $a_i^n = e$ for all $i$. But $|a_iy| = \text{lcm}(|y|, |a_i|) \nmid n$ for all $i$, so $\{a_iy \mid i = 1, 2, \ldots\}$ is an infinite set of elements, none of whose orders divide $n$.